# Schedule a task in days or months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to schedule a job in a far future. I seen tools like delayed_job can do some tasks asynchronously but it seems to be used for tasks scheduled in 5 minutes. Another solution can be to do a cron but it's not very efficient.

Is there a better way? I want to be sure than, if I reboot the server, tasks scheduled are not deleted.

Comment: take a look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem

Comment: it seems to be useful. Do you if it's possible to specify a date? For exemple, I want to execute the call function the 23 december 2014.

Comment: seems like `every '0 0 23 12 *' do` would work for this. It can take `cron` syntax so `minute hour day month day-of-week`. So this will run every December 23rd at 12:00am regardless of what day of the week that is.

Comment: Add this comment in anwser and I will accept it.

Comment: I see you accepted `rufus-scheduler` no hard feelings :). Just thought I would mention that this is an in-process scheduler. Meaning if the task is supposed to run the calling process must be running first. If your server is down or the application is down at the time this is supposed to run it won't until that time comes around again which in your case is a year later. `whenever` will actually schedule `cron` jobs for you instead of relying on the running process.

Comment: you are right. I changed my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem

Seems like using

```
every '0 0 23 12 *' do 
  ...
end
```

would work for this. It can take cron syntax so `minute hour day month day-of-week`. So this will run every December 23rd at 12:00am regardless of what day of the week that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). The example taken from the documentation shows how to do it:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new


scheduler.at '2030/12/12 23:30:00' do
  # do something at a given point in time
end
```

It also allows you to schedule in diferent ways:

```
scheduler.in '10d' do
  # do something in 10 days
end

scheduler.every '3h' do
  # do something every 3 hours
end

scheduler.cron '5 0 * * *' do
  # do something every day, five minutes after midnight
  # (see "man 5 crontab" in your terminal)
end
```